# lm_robust get reference level of factor variable

Tags: r, regression

How do I automatically get a line showing the reference level of factor variables in the regression output below? I want to achieve this bc I like to conveniently pass the output and the reference level names on for plotting purposes.

```
library(estimatr)

N = 20000
x = rbinom(N, 1, prob = 0.4)
y = 0.4*x + rnorm(N)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df$x <- factor(df$x)

lm_robust(df, formula = y ~ x)

# What I want:

              Estimate  Std. Error   t value      Pr(>|t|)     CI Lower   CI Upper    DF
(Intercept) 0.01226214 0.009170196  1.337173  1.811815e-01 -0.005712206 0.03023648 19998
x0          0 or NA... etc.  
x1          0.36736184 0.014482711 25.365544 9.761365e-140  0.338974534 0.39574915 19998
```

Comment: Looks like there are only categorical variables. You can fit without an intercept. ‘y~0+x1’

Comment: Its mostly about getting the names of the reference categories for further use (e.g. plotting). Also The example is just a MWE for simplicity

Comment: Is there really no way other than doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure from your question, so below is a try. `emmeans` is a useful package for determining the individual estimates, and you need to use a package that it is "compatible" with.. So if it is robust estimate, you can use `rlm` from MASS and do:

```
library(MASS)
library(emmeans)

N = 20000
x = sample(0:3,N,replace=TRUE)
y = 0.4*(x==1) + rnorm(N)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df$x <- factor(df$x)


emmeans(fit,"x")
 x  emmean     SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 0  0.0143 0.0146 NA   -0.0143    0.0429
 1  0.4096 0.0146 NA    0.3811    0.4382
 2  0.0108 0.0148 NA   -0.0181    0.0398
 3 -0.0187 0.0147 NA   -0.0475    0.0101
```